# PHP - Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, html, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted.

I have installed PHP 5.3 version and have added  gc_collect_cycles();

where needed.

I am working with PHP simple dom library with good number of URLs (websites) to check them whether they are good (it checks for iframe and embed tags in the HTML, if there are iframe or embed tags with SRC atrribute different than youtube,metacafe or dailymotion will flag the URL as NOT good.

Websites are mine (not scraping anyone).

Why there is memory leak if clear() method, null, unset and gc_collect_cycles is called everytime at the end of the loop.

```
   foreach ($data as $blog) {
         $htm = file_get_html($blog['blogurl']);

         if ($htm->find('iframe', 0)) {

        foreach ($htm->find('iframe') as $if) {
          if (! preg_match('/(dailymotion\.com|metacafe\.com|youtube\.com)/i', @ $if->src)) {
            //this URL i
            mark_url_not_good($blog['blogurl']);

            $htm->clear();
            $htm = null;
            unset($htm);
            gc_collect_cycles();
            continue 2;
          }
        }



      }
            $htm->clear();
            $htm = null;
            unset($htm);
            gc_collect_cycles();


     }
```

Comment: Are you connecting to a DB as part of your script?

Comment: The connection is done 1 time BEFORE the loop.

Comment: You need to post some more details or a simplified version of your code.

Comment: @user1316394 you can type the `@` symbol and then type the first few letters of the persons name you want to reply to, it should bring up a box - click that to auto-insert their name into your comment, make sure others are notified of your comment. +1 for adding your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why there is memory leak if clear() method, null, unset and gc_collect_cycles is called everytime at the end of the loop.

Well, there might be just a memory leak inside the *simple dom library*, garbage collection won't fix that. Without seeing your code, it's hard to give suggestions what's best to do in this situation.

You might want to replace the scrape functionality with a more native parser like `DOMDocument`.

Comment: The code fetches URLs from database and loops them.
in the loop new object of simple dom library is created at the beginning of the loop to handle the HTML.

Comment: @user1316394 Okay, so that's *what* it does. *How* does it do it? We need to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

what you really need is:

```
$htm->__destruct();
```

to clear the simple_html_dom memory each time you don't need the $htm info anymore.  e.g. use this where you have:

```
$htm->clear();
```

Note the double underscore!